# Problems counting number of exchanges and comparisons in bubble sort

Tags: c++

I know that a reverse ordered list should yield theta(n^2) number of comparisons and theta(n^2) number of exchanges for bubble sort. In my sample code I am using a list of size n = 10. I implemented counters for the numComparisons and numExchanges, and although this doesn't seem very complicated, I can't figure out why my results don't yield 100 comparisons and 100 exchanges. Am I really far off target?

```
void testList::bubbleSort()
{

    int k = 10;
    bool flag = true;

    while(flag)
    {
        k = k - 1;
        flag = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if( vecPtr[j] > vecPtr[j+1])
            {   


                int temp = vecPtr[j];
                vecPtr[j] = vecPtr[j+1];
                vecPtr[j+1] = temp;
                numExchanges += 1;
                flag = true;
            }
            numComparisons++;
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting output:

Original List:  `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

Sorted List:   `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comparisons: `45`

Exchanges: `45`

I also tried this implementation, but my results were the same:

```
void testList::bubbleSort()
{

    int temp;
    for(long i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(long j = 0; j < 10-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (vecPtr[j] > vecPtr[j+1])
            {
                temp        = vecPtr[j];
                vecPtr[j]     = vecPtr[j+1];
                vecPtr[j+1]   = temp;
                numExchanges++;
            }
            numComparisons++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Approximately N<sup>2</sup>/2 comparisons and exchanges are expected.

In particular, the inner loop starts the current value of the outer loop. So, on the first iteration, it traverses the entire array. On each subsequent iteration, it traverses one fewer item in the array.

So, the number of iterations of the inner loop is N + N-1 + N-2 ... 1. On average, that's approximately N/2.

If you want to get more precise, there's one more detail to consider: the inner loop iterates from i+1...N, so its largest value is N-1 iterations, not N iterations.

Therefore, instead of being precisely N<sup>2</sup>/2, it's really N * (N-1)/2. In your case, that 10*9/2 = 45.

That's the count for the number of comparisons. For swaps, you get some percentage of that, depending on the number of items that are out of order. In your specific case, all items are always out of order (because you're starting with reverse order) so you do a swap for every comparison. With any other ordering, you'd expect the number of swaps to be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

45 = 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1, so for the exchanges this is correct, but for the comparisons I think there must be a mistake somewhere. Edit: You implemented a slightly more intelligent version than the standard bubble sort, that's why you have only 45 comparisons instead of 90 (it's not 100, one iteration takes 9 comparisons).